# includes files not being found through require_once()

Tags: php, path, include, require

Hey guys before I begin my question, I'm gonna paste a photo of my folders structure so it will be easier to visualize.

[image]

Okay so, in the `header.php` highlighted above, I have this line of code:

```
<?php require_once("admin/admin_pages/includes/init.php"); ?>
```

And in that init.php file:

```
<?php
require_once("functions.php");
require_once("db_config.php");
require_once("database.php");
require_once("user.php");
require_once("session.php");
require_once("photo.php");
require_once("db_object.php");
?>
```

However, when I try to open the `index.php` file located in my root directory it gives this error:

[image]

The init.php that's being `required_once` is working. However it doesn't seem to find the files(which are in the same directory as the init.php) that are required in the `init.php` file itself. Why is this happening?

Note: All the paths work when I am playing around in my `admin/admin_pages/index.php` page.

[image]

EDIT: This is a screenshot of the contents in my includes folder.

```
<?php
//Just in case an includes file is not called in the init.php file.
function classAutoloader($class)
{
    $class = strtolower($class);
    $path = "includes/{$class}.php";

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        require_once($path);
    } else {
        die("The file named {$class}.php was not found.");
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('classAutoloader');

function redirect($location)
{
    header("Location: {$location}");
}
?>
```

EDIT: This is what is giving the **error message** FYI. I have setup an autoloader function. However, the file is not missing and should be loaded either way.

Comment: If the error is only displaying for `db_object.php` then that means other files you require_once'd before are there. Can you show the contents of the folder `dmin/admin_pages/includes/`?

Comment: It is hard to play with paths with files that are already included. It's easier to use `__DIR__` or a base directory. Is `db_object` in `admin/admin_pages/includes/`?

Comment: Is one of your included files using `chmod()` or something like that?

Comment: hey guys, yes I have just print screened it. Also, yes I've been trying to figure out how to use __DIR__ and looking for ways to restructure my files. I will post my solution ASAP if I find it.

Comment: By any chance, is there any other file that is trying to include `db_object.php`?

Comment: no, none of my files are using chmod(). Keep in mind that all these works If I am on my administrator page. The problem only occurs when I'm trying to access the files on my index.php on root directory.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Could you post the `photo.php` content? It's the last file that works.

Comment: only the init.php file is trying to include the db_obect.php. And the init.php file is being included in both admin/admin_pages/includes/header.php and includes/header.php

Comment: But you are using require_once, so  which is including it first and only?

Comment: If all your files are containing classes, I would suggest you to use an autoloader instead of requiring them by yourself.

Comment: Ah yes i have forgotten to mention that @AnthonyB I have an  autoloader and it is the function thats giving this error message. I will update my question.

Comment: @Bane, Using an autoloader is great! But I would suggest to include your autoloader in your main index.php, and then only use the autoloader, no manual require. And use `__DIR__` only in the autoloader if needed.

Comment: Just a note about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because it was a bit hard to understand the structure at the beginning.

Comment: A piece of the puzzle that is missing is where does the autoloader code sit in the file system, and where and how is this called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thank you all for your input. I have finally found the problem with my code. It is not because of the autoloader function.

I did not know that the order of the files being called in the `init.php` mattered. I have simply re-ordered the `require_once()` statements.

The `db_object.php` file is actually the file that contains the parent class for my objects (photos and users). The `photo.php` and `users.php` contain inherited classes from the `db_object.php`. Which would made sense on why we need to find the `db_object.php` first.

**Before:**

```
<?php
require_once("functions.php");
require_once("db_config.php");
require_once("database.php");
require_once("user.php");
require_once("session.php");
require_once("photo.php");
require_once("db_object.php");
?>
```

**After:**

```
<?php
require_once("functions.php");
require_once("db_config.php");
require_once("database.php");
require_once("db_object.php");
require_once("user.php");
require_once("session.php");
require_once("photo.php");
?>
```

Comment: Although this prevents your autoloader from throwing an error, it shouldn't really have thrown an error in the first place. The whole point of the autoloader is that it is a last resort in case a class cannot be found, you're now just preventing the autoloader being necessary, you're not fixing the fact that it doesn't work for `~/index.php`.

Comment: so are you saying that the order of the require_once statements don't matter at all? Even if some of the files such as user.php and photo.php have classes that are inheriting from a class in the db_object.php file? It was a weird fix, I know I'm still trying to understand it.

Comment: I am not saying that it doesn't matter -- your question has clearly shown that it can matter, I am saying that it shouldn't matter. Because **1)** if `photo.php` and `user.php` _require_ `db_object.php`, the latter should actually be `required_once` by those files. If your `index.php` also requires it, you may still explicitly  call `require_once` from there. And **2)** you could (and should) get rid of all the `require_once` statements and use an autoloader. Even more so 'cause you already have one that just needs a little tweak to work from all of your different locations.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

Since you've made some edits, in which you've presented us -- among other things -- with the existence of an autoloader, I've re-read your question. Two important things that jump out:

1. This issue occurs in your `index.php` located in the root of your website.
2. The error that's printed originates from `classAutoloader()`.
3. (You're not having any probblems with `admin/admin_pages/index.php`.)

It would seem that this is still a path issue similar to the one mentioned below. When the autoloader is called from `~/index.php` it's checking whether your root contains `includes/db_object.php` and that's not the case.

You can fix this by specifying the path to your includes folder relative to the autoloader file, something like this:

```
$path = __DIR__ ."/path/to/includes/{$class}.php";
```

Although I don't see any problems with this solution, it doesn't look very elegant to me. Alternatively you could specify the path from your root.

---

### Issues with your init.php file.

By requiring `admin/admin_pages/includes/init.php` you're running the code in `init.php` from the file that's requiring it. If that makes sense. You could write the following in `header.php` and it would behave the same as requiring `init.php`:

```
<?php
require_once("functions.php");
require_once("db_config.php");
require_once("database.php");
require_once("user.php");
require_once("session.php");
require_once("photo.php");
require_once("db_object.php");
?>
```

You may notice that that wouldn't make sense, since those paths aren't correct when called from `header.php`. You can fix this by using the `__DIR__` constant:

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of
>   the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory. ~ [***The Manual***](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

---

With the aforementioned information you could probably figure it out yourself, but to make my answer complete, change the code in `init.php` to:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/functions.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/db_config.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/database.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/user.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/session.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/photo.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/db_object.php";
?>
```

**Note that:**

1. `require_once` isn't a function but a statement, so you call it as such. The same goes for `require`, `include` and `include_once`.
2. Per your question only the requiring of `db_object.php` fails... That seems kinda strange.

---

**Pro-tip** (as mentioned in the comments by AnyhonyB):

> One of the biggest annoyances is having to write a long list of needed
>   includes at the beginning of each script (one for each class).
>
> In PHP 5, this is no longer necessary. The spl_autoload_register()
>   function registers any number of autoloaders, enabling for classes and
>   interfaces to be automatically loaded if they are currently not
>   defined. By registering autoloaders, PHP is given a last chance to
>   load the class or interface before it fails with an error. ~ [***The Manua*l**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, it is strange. I have updated my question because I forgot to include the autloader function code I have implemented. This is what is giving the error message. However it should still find the the db_object.php file as it is not missing.

Comment: I've  upvoted because `__DIR__` fixes the problem, it avoids the problems with files included in an included files and stuffs like that. But according to me, using `__DIR__` is not flexible enough, an autoloader solution would be good. And it's a bit tedious to use `__DIR__` in all include.

Comment: @AnthonyB I 100% agree that an autoloader should be used in this case, but that's simply not the answer to the question _why are include files not being found through require_once()?_

Comment: @Niellles you are right indeed. Your answer is valid. But it's usual to answer to the main question and then suggest a possibly better solution.

Comment: @AnthonyB I am sorta new to answering questions on SO... or at least have only recently started doing it on a regular basis. I've added the tip to my answer as additional information. Thanks!

Comment: @Bane I am a bit confused as to why you'd use the multiple `require_once` statements in `init.php` in addition to an autoloader...

Comment: @Niellles hey Nielles, I am looking to implement your suggestion and I will keep you posted on that. Yes, it may be redundant to have both, but I've been taught to implement both the require_once and autoloader for safety reasons just incase I forget to include a file...the autoloader will be able to do it for me. That's the only reason why I'm using both.

Comment: You must also take include paths into account.  Now we know about the autoloader, what is likely happening is that some code is trying to include a file via that, and that's the issue with the paths.  So actually this isn't an answer.

Comment: @Progrock Good point. It's clearly the autoloader throwing this error and not the require statement. I should've noticed, although we didn't know about the autoloader yet. Any comments on my edited answer?

Comment: hey all, thank you for trying to help. I have found the problem with my code!

Comment: @Niellles It's really better with the autoloader part! And if the autoloader was good enough, it would have included the `Db_Object` class without needed of `require_once` everywhere. According to me, with the part on the autoloader you have the answer.

Comment: @AnthonyB I agree with the "if autoloader was good enough part" and have pointed that out in a comment to OPs answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but may help:

Consider the following.

If we have three files in the same directory:

a.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'b.php';
require_once 'c.php';
```

b.php:

```
<?php
class B extends C
{}
```

c.php:

```
<?php
class C
{}
```

If I run a.php I get this output:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'C' not found in /var/www/stackoverflow/req_test2/b.php on line 3
```

This shows that order matters with require calls.

If I swap out the contents of a.php for the following and run it:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register();

$b = new B;
var_dump($b);
```

I get this output:

```
object(B)#1 (0) {
}
```

spl_autoload_register() without parameters here uses the default implementation of [spl_autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php):  a reference to a class named Foo, will look to include a file foo.php from your include path.

The initialisation of B here references class C, and the autoloader above will take care of requiring the appropriate files as needed.

I'd recommend placing each class definition in a file of its own.  With a one-one mapping of filename to class.  You may also be interested in the [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) style.

Declare your autoloader early.  Utility functions can also be included upfront.

A fix for your code would be to add your includes folder to your include path, and to change your require line to `$path = "{$class}.php";`.  I would personally remove the die line within your autoloader, as you may need to register more than one autoloader - these are stackable as are your include paths.

Answer (score 0):

Put the db_object.php file above the users.php file in the init.php file and it will be found. I'm working on the same course and thats the solution